# trying to change iframe location from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, iframe

i have many stores every store got latitude, longitude when i click location icon for any store i send latitude, longitude to javascript function and change iframe src in js function and i show model showing the iframe but the iframe not showing the location here is the code.

**iframe error**
[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) refused to connect.

**icon button**
`<a onclick="getLocation({{$store->lat}},{{$store->lon}})" data-toggle="modal" href="#edit_location"><i style="font-size: 25px; color: #009688;" class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a>`

**iframe in model**

```
<div class="mapouter mt-3"><div class="gmap_canvas"><iframe  id="gmap_canvas" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></iframe><a href="https://fnftest.net" style="display:none">fnf test playground remake</a><style>.mapouter{position:relative;text-align:right;height:400px;width:100%;}</style><a href="https://www.googlemapsiframegenerator.com" style="display:none">Google Maps Iframe Generator - Free Html Embed Code</a><style>.gmap_canvas{overflow:hidden;background:none!important;height:400px;width:100%;}</style></div></div>
```

**javascript function**

```
function getLocation(lat,lon){
    var loc = document.getElementById('gmap_canvas');
    loc.src = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + lat + ',' + lon + '&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed';
}
```

**Note**
when i give iframe src any static location without js it works the problem when i change the src from js the error show

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your JS function located - I am assuming it is in an external script resource, and not directly contained *inside* the HTML document?

```
loc.src = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + lat + ',' + lon + '&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed';
```

Replace the `&amp;` with a single `&` then. Encoding this as `&amp;` would only be necessary, if the context was HTML - but that is not the case, if this code resides in an external JS resource.

Google does give me the "connection refused" message when I try to use this URL with `&amp;` (more precise, the browser said it has `X-Frame-Options` set to `Deny`), but it appears to work fine with just `&`.